# Sitecore MVC - An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request

Tags: c#, .net, exception, dictionary, sitecore

I am getting the below exception and no clue of the class/method name. Just it shows me the fully qualified type names. But which dictionary? I debugged and couldn't find out the exact place as at one point, straightaway it throws this exception. Its a MVC application (Sitecore MVC)

Any help please? or clue on how to debug or fix this issue?

> Description: An unhandled exception occurred.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type ProductController but this dictionary requires a model item of type ProductViewController

Answer (score 1):

One of your renderings is trying to pass in the wrong object type from the `Controller` to the `Razor` file.

Look through the renderings that you have on the page that is generating the exception. One of the razor scripts will have a model tag something like this:

```
@model Namespace.ProductViewController
```

But the controller action, or view rendering is setup to pass in a `ProductController` object. You need to update either the view or the controller action so that the correct model is passed in, or the correct model is expected.